# How to write reusable controllers code for dojox.mobile views

Tags: javascript, view, dojo, controller, dojox.mobile

I'm writing an application based on dojox.mobile framework. I'm using dojo 1.9.
Some views of the application are really similar and have a lot of things in common so I would like to create a general view and extend it to specialize it.

Given that every view has a controller, I tried to create a parent controller (which is a module defined via the define function) and then tried to extend it, but without success.

What I am doing is creating a GeneralController.js like the following:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/on"], 
    function(declare,lang, on){
        return declare("AppControllers/GeneralController",[],{
            init: function(){
                     //do something in GeneralController
            },

            beforeActivate: function(){
                     //...
            }
        })
    }
);
```

and a View1.js controller like the following:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/on",
        "AppControllers/GeneralController"], 
    function(declare,lang, on, general){
        return declare(general,{
            init: function(){
                     //do something in this View1.js controller
                     this.inherited();//do what was in general
            },

            beforeActivate: function(){
                     //...
            }
        })
    }
);
```

and in the config.json I have:

```
{
    //...
    "views":{
        //...
        "View1":{
           "template":"AppTemplates/View1.html",
           "controller":"AppControllers/View1.js"
        },
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

The dojo.mobile framework seems not accept view controllers written as dojo class (via declare). 
How can I obtain a hierarchy of view controllers?

Comment: have you looked into dojox/app seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the best solution for me is to use dojox/app, as suggested by @tik27.

I was trying to extend the controller module associated to the view (see *AppControllers/View1.js* in the config below) but that module is simply mixed to the View. 
If I want to get a classy handling of the Views I can leverage the *type* property (see again the config json excerpt below).

config.json:

```
{
    //...
    "views":{
        //...
        "View1":{
           "template":"AppTemplates/View1.html",
           "controller":"AppControllers/View1.js"
           "type":"my/SpecializedView.js"
        },
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

To do this I have to simply extend *dojox/app/View* in my *my/GenericView* which will contain custom properties and methods. Then I can write SpecializedViews extending *my/GenericView*:

my/GenericView.js

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojox/app/View"
], function(declare, View) {
    return declare("my/GenericView",[View], {
        customProp: "example", // Default content
        customMethod:function(){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

my/SpecializedView.js

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "my/GenericView"
], function(declare, GenericView) {
    return declare(GenericView, {
        init:function(){
            console.log(this.customProp);//will print "example"
        }
        customMethod:function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);//recall parent class' method
            //extend parent class' method
        }
    });
});
```

Anyway, the title of this question refers to dojox/mobile so you can find a fully dojox/mobile example il this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/5PCrb/ by @Dimitri M

Answer (score 1):

Like @tik27 said, `dojox/app` might be your solution. However, we found that the documentation of the `dojox/app` section was lacking good examples so to lower the learning curve for other people, we made our own small framework (for `dojox/mobile` with IBM Worklight) which improves reusability.

We actually made a "base controller" module, extending `dojox/mobile/View` using a template like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojox/mobile/View",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"
], function(declare, View, TemplatedMixin) {
    return declare([View, TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: "<header>My header</header> ${!content} <footer>footer</footer>", 
        content: null // Default content
    });
});
```

As you can see we have a standard template with a header and a footer, but we also use a placeholder called `content`. The general part of the template (in this case that header/footer) can you put here.

The view/controller modules extending this base controller look like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "./ControllerMixin"
], function(declare, ControllerMixin) {
    return declare([ControllerMixin], {
        content: "This is the content"
    });
});
```

Because we enter the `content` property here, it will be placed at the position of the `${!content}` we earlier defined.

If you need ot use widgets in your template you can also choose `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer pointed me the right way of solving the problem!

Comment: Great :) I also made a full `dojox/mobile` example. It doesn't inherit  much (except the titlebar and the scrollableview), but I think you get the point: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/5PCrb/

Comment: I don't know how to handle the answer to this question, but I have added your jsfiddle to the answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/20706052/1085383